# Cannot print bigint with Fat Free Framework

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

Hello I try to retrieve a value with fat free framework from mysql . Value is stored as bigint in db but when I retrieve it prints 2147483647 . Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion #1: show the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a 32 bit system, 2147483647 is the largest possible integer that can be stored. You have two options.

Option 1: Convert the integer to a string using MySQL's [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) during the query, so that PHP reads/stores it as a string rather than integer

Option 2: Use a library like [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) to manage & manipulate large integers